# Good practice to give email address for a job in format [firstname][currentyear]@domain.com?

Tags: software-industry, resume, job-search, email

Normally, I saw experts saying that your email should include your first and last name like in a format `[firstname][lastname]@[domain.com]`, but my email address includes my first name and current year. Is it a good practice to give an email address for a job like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

We have said this before, but:

Realistically, as long as your email address isn't offensive or stupid, and doesn't make you look like someone who would rather work for the competition, ***nobody cares.*** They aren't going to memorize it, just cut-and-paste it a few times when corresponding with you. It can be complete nonsense, like my own nickname/UID. It can be based on your name. Or a non-controversial hobby, or ... anything, really., As long as it doesn't cause them to immediately discard your application because they wouldn't want to work with you, it is Good Enough.

You have more important things to worry about. Don't waste time on this one.

Comment: Do be careful, if you're using a nickname or an address that you're using for other purposes, a quick google search might reveal more than you'd want. Stackoverflow questions, instagram accounts, forums or sites that you'd not show people who don't know you...

Comment: If you don't want folks to see it, don't do it on line. Under any name.  Connections can be made that you wouldn't expect.

Comment: keshlam: sometimes compartmentalization is not a bad idea. It's good to have a friend who you can tell stuff to you can't tell noone else, or to ask an internet forum for help without the whole world knowing your marriage is in shambles. But yes, incognito mode, VPN, tor & throwaways all have their purpose, too...

Answer (score 0):

If your name is firstname lastname then your best possible email address would be firstname.lastname@isp.com or flastname@isp.com. If your name is Joe Smith then you are not going to get that email address, that's just a fact. So you take the best you can.

Something like joseph2016@gmail.com isn't perfect. I'd prefer your last name in there. But it's not a real problem, like titanic.lover@gmail.com might be.

PS. I'm assuming a private email address, not company. If you run your own email server, you can have any email address you like.

Comment: My email address is `[firstname]2016@gmail.com` Is it good for a job?  Thank's!

Comment: Why are these better than `[first]@[first][last].[tld]`, `[first]@[last].[tld]`, `me@[first][last].[tld]`, etc?

Comment: I'd go for joe-smith-5696@gmail.com where "5696" is a random number you pick.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan Use joe-smith+${RANDOM NUMBER}@gmail.com.  For all random numbers, the email will get sent to joe-smith@gmail.com (https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~watrous/plus-signs-in-email-addresses.html).  Change the random number for each application you send.  When and if you find yourself subscribed to cat facts, you will know who did it.